# Is there a more efficient way to setup alternate elements if one isn't found on Python Selenium?

Tags: python, performance, selenium

I have a few python 2.7 scripts that use selenium to scrape data from a website. I want to have 'backup' elements, so if the first element isn't found it will go to the next and try that one. This way if one thing on the website is changed it wont mess up my entire script. Here is what i'm using now, but I have a good amount of elements and want to know if there is a more efficient and shorter way to do this without raising an exception.

```
locators = [
    (By.NAME, "email"),
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='email']"),
    (By.XPATH, '//*body/div/div[2]/div/'),
    (By.TAG_NAME, 'label')
    ]
for by, value in locators:
    try:
        elem = driver.find_element(by, value)
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass      
elem.send_keys('emailaddress@email.com')
```

Comment: One thing you may want to consider: The time cost associated with this is in the failed attempts. So if I were to do this, I'd have it log failures, which one did succeed and issue a report at the end of the run. That way it succeeds *and* you get notification that the element has changed and the script should be updated to reflect this. That's why I'd say leave it as is (plus logging): you'll get best possible performance and when you don't, you'll know it and know what needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem to think about and performance measurements would really be required to get a sense of speed of different approaches.

**Combining locators into a single expression**

As you may know, every `find_element()` call would result into a ["FIND_ELEMENT"](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#find-element) selenium HTTP command sent through [Json Wire protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol). This introduces a lot of overhead especially if you need to do it continuously until a desired element is found.

In order to reduce on the number of HTTP requests/responses, we can combine all the locators into a single XPath expression, something like:

```
expression = "(//*[@name = 'email']|//*body/div/div[2]/div/|//label)"
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(expression)
```

This, of course, for starters, seriously *reduces readability* (though, you may come up with a helper function that would generate a single expression out of a list of different locators). And, there are multiple DOM "scans" involved which will make the expression slow - even though, I would expect this to be faster than your current approach, especially with an increasing number of `locators`.

**Using an HTML parser**

You may also pass the "page source" (`driver.page_source`) to the *HTML parser*, like `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to figure out which of the locator is valid for your element.

---

You may also think of some other optimizations:

- instead of calling `find_element*()` on the `driver` instance, you may call it on the parent container element where you expect your desired element to be found - this can be the `body` element, or it can be a, say, `div` element with `class="container"`, depending on your target site layout
- to follow up @TemporalWolf's thought expressed in the comment: you may keep track of how often each of the locators worked adjusting their priority and the order in which you are going to try them during the next run. It can, for instance, be an SQLite database with a (LOCATOR_TYPE, LOCATOR_VALUE, SCORE) table.
- you can start up multiple browsers trying multiple locators in parallel and see which one succeeds - this is more tricky and complex, but, depending on how critical the performance is and how big the number of locators can get, this may be a viable option
- use latest `selenium` package and browser versions

Note that you may get different performance results in different browsers - experiment and measure.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I am interested in combining them into a single xpath expression. I don't think i've seen this done before, can you give me a little more info on how this works? I see you combined the CSS, Xpath, and Tag Name with a '//' separating them. is this using the first element that is located, or what? In regards to the experimenting with different locators and browsers, I planned on doing this as a final tune once I get everything else finished. I'm currently using PhantomJS, is there another headless browser that you would suggest to try? Thanks.

Comment: @Ecom1414 right, basically any locator technique can be replaced with an XPath one (even though it is considered that xpaths are generally slower than others, but there are multiple things to take into account - it's not that simple). The `|` means "or", `//` will start the search from the very root node of the tree. As far as PhantomJS, I think I've seen some helpful flags to, for example, turn images off, that may potentially speed things up. You may also try something like Chrome or Firefox under a virtual display. Or, take a look at splash and scrapy-splash. Thanks.

Comment: With the locators provided, you can craft a CSS selector that will combine these 3, just insert a comma between each. It should be faster than the comparable XPath locator. If you were going to keep the XPath locator, I would put a space around the `|`s to make it a little more readable.